# Bing Maps control XamlParseException

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-7, geolocation, bing-maps

I'm trying to use Bing Maps control on Windows Phone application, but when I launch the page where the map control is located, I get this error:

```
Failed to create a 'System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate' from the text '0,0'. [Line: 32 Position: 58]
```

Here's my XAML, though there's nothing special here:

```
<my:Map Height="224"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="7,4,0,0"
        Name="map1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="443"
        Loaded="map1_Loaded"
        ViewChangeStart="map1_ViewChangeStart">
    <my:MapLayer Name="lMain">
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="20" Height="20"
                 my:MapLayer.Position="0,0"
                 Name="ppLocation"
                 Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </my:MapLayer>
</my:Map>
```

I tried adding coordinates using this code:

```
GeoCoordinate ld = (Application.Current as App).curentLocation;
Location ppLoc = new Location();
GeoCoordinate g = new GeoCoordinate();

ppLoc.Latitude = ld.Latitude;
ppLoc.Longitude = ld.Longitude;
ppLoc.Altitude = ld.Altitude;

map1.SetView(ppLoc, 10);

//update pushpin location and show
MapLayer.SetPosition(ppLocation, ppLoc);
ppLocation.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

But it throws "NullReferenceExcpetion" on  map1.SetView(ppLoc, 10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you set the `my:MapLayer.Position="0,0"` for the `Ellipse`. Either you shouldn't set it at all, or you should set it to a valid coordinate.

Also, your `NullReferenceExcpetion` is because of `map1` being null when you attempt to set `map1.SetView(ppLoc, 10);`.

Comment: Removed "my:MapLayer.Position="0,0"" and now everything works. Thanks